# How to convert large .mp4 file (~1.5GB) to .gif without my iMac crashing?

Tags: imac, file-conversion

As it says in title. I couldn't find a way to convert it with a file conversion system already on my computer using a Google search, and nor could I find any online converters without a size limit.

Eventually I did find a website which recommended uploading it to Keynote as a one-slide presentation and saving it as a .gif, but I suppose my computer, as it's quite old, couldn't handle downloading it and crashed.

What would be a good way to convert it with minimal stress on my system? Download time isn't a problem as long as it gets done.

Comment: break up the video file

Comment: A 1.5 Gb mp4 video is going to be hours long. Why do you need this as an animated GIF?

Answer (score 2):

For a file this large you won't find a free online converter. As it would take up to much computational power and the resulting .gif file will be a multiple of the 1.5GB input file.

Best thing you could do is download [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) and convert it on your local machine. Depending on your input file and quality requirements, you may need to experiment a bit with the various options. [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](https://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality) is a good starting point for this.

In general it would be interesting to know why you need such a large video file as a .gif file. Because the .gif format probably isn't very well suited for the application in mind.